# Adding Python to C++: not finding Python.h

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, ubuntu

I want to add some functions written in Python to my C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile this program using commend  `g++ main.cpp -Wall -o main`
I have an error: `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

I was trying to solve the problem by installing `python2.7 -dev` by `sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev`, but it didn't help. Can someone suggest what more I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler where to find the Python headers.  For example, on some systems you'd do this:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/python2.7 ...
```

Comment: I made `g++ -I usr/include/python2.7/Python.h main.cpp -Wall -o main` but I still have the same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You added Python.h to the command line.  Don't do that, do what I wrote (the ... is meant to be your main.cpp and the rest).  Read the manual regarding the `-I` option.

Comment: @Rop you're also missing a leading / on that path

Comment: @JohnZwinck For my the commend: `g++ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 main.cpp -Wall -o main` works good now.

Answer (score 3):

[Additional note](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html):

> Since Python may define some pre-processor definitions which affect
>   the standard headers on some systems, you must include `Python.h` before
>   any standard headers are included.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer, as it does not solve the problem, but rather attempts to head off an upcoming additional problem after the main one is fixed.